# I'm trying to implement a menu in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

I'm implementing a menu, but it always throws me the same error, I have the same configuration in an earlier app and it works for me in this one, I tried many things and I can not fix it.

I tried to change the support dependencies several times: appcompat and upport: design but it does not work.

Error:

```
08-18 13:23:22.035 4143-4143/xxxx.com.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: xxxx.com.xxxx, PID: 4143 

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable' appears in /data/app/xxxx.com.xxxx-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex)

at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.<clinit>(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:111) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.get(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:85) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 

at xxxx.com.xxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">



    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx.com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: What's on the line 14 of you MainActivity?

Comment: @MehdiB.   WHERE?

Comment: rephrasing, what's the code written on the line 14 of your Activity class: MainActivity.java?

Comment: You're most likely referencing a non existing resource on your menu `navigation_menu.xml`

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchFieldError: Thrown if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field.

Normally, this error is caught by the compiler so check your project before compiling for any typos or missing menu resources as you are using navigation view; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.